# Can catch statement catch syntax errors in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, syntax-error

Kangax blog has a code example: [*§*](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#expr-vs-decl)

```
 try {
    (var x = 5); // grouping operator can only contain expression, not a statement (which `var` is)
  } catch(err) {
    // SyntaxError
  }
```

Since the syntax error at line 2 would affect the "syntax of the entire code", what's the point of the `catch` statement here?

Is `catch` able to catch syntax errors in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, javascript parser will generate an error, so it will never catch it.

http://jsbin.com/oluje5/edit

Maybe his intention was to point out the wrong syntax (grouping operator can only contain expression, not a statement), but the try / catch statement is useless.

Moreover, the comment `//syntaxError` inside catch let suppose that the catch will do something.

Comment: Certain engines may treat syntax errors as runtime errors and vice versa. For example, `if (false) { new Object = 1; }` is treated as a syntax error in Firefox even though the specs permit this.

Comment: @user123444555621, It's a syntax error (and thus uncatchable) in Chrome too. Are you sure the specs permit this? Which specs?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is correct. Using a `try...catch` doesn't help against syntax errors.

The script block won't run at all if there is a syntax error keeping it from being parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax errors wont be caught by try/catch, as you can't wrap variable assignments in brackets like that.